# React Redux SSR saga run saga promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have the following code, I am trying to do SSR with React, redux-saga etc

The output from the consoles, shows in the following order:

```
data2: { todos: { status: 'NOT_REQUESTED', data: [] } } // initialState
data1: { todos:
{ status: 'SSR_SUCCESS',
 data:
  [ [Object],.....
  ]
 }
} // fetched data
....then initialState gets returned from the function before the promise resolves
```

I know I must be missing something simple....  I want to return from this function with the data ( and store) that comes after the toPromise resolves.

```
const fetchDataForRender = (req, res) => {
  let data = initialState; // = { todos: { status: 'NOT_REQUESTED', data: [] } }
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor });

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  );

  const url = req.url;
  const sagas = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

 ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<ServerAppToRender url={url} store={store} />);

  sagas.toPromise().then(() => {
    data = store.getState();
    console.log('data1:', data); // logs the fetched data successfully
  });

  console.log('data2: ', data);

  store.dispatch(END); 

  return { data, store }; // initial state gets returned as 'data'    
};
```

Any help in getting this working would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: promise by nature is async, you are expecting you return statement to wait after promise returns which dont seem to be the case in your code.

Comment: @Rikin - can you show me what you mean? I have tried doing a return statement in the then block.
I am wanting to wait for the promise to resolve before  then returning out the fetchDataForRender with the newly fetched data

Comment: at line 16 you are waiting for a promise to return and then assigning `data = store.getState()` which you are expecting in your `return { data, store }`. The fact is that once line 16 executes, it registers the callback and put it in the event loop to listen for promise to return, it dont wait for it at that line rather moves on and executes line 21, 23, and 25 which returns `{data, store}` value at that time which is initial state at that moment.

Comment: You can probably attach async to line 1 as `const fetchDataForRender = async (req, res) => {` and then await for promise to return and then execute your code line `await   sagas.toPromise().then(() => {` that way you are guaranteed that data is set to what you want.